# change jquery code to be a function

Tags: jquery

I have this code in jquery that searches a HTML table:

```
$('#contact_search').keyup(function() {
            var $rows = $('#contact_table tbody tr');
            var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

            $rows.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();
        });
```

but i want to make it into a function so i can use it in other places too, i have tried:

```
function ContactSearch() {
            var $rows = $('#contact_table tbody tr');
            var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

            $rows.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();
        }
```

so then i can call it like this instead:

```
if($("#contact_search").val()) {
    ContactSearch();
}
$('#contact_search').keyup(function() {
    ContactSearch();
});
```

its calling the function okay (i added `alert("");` at the top of the function which shows) but its not searching the HTML table.

Comment: just add `contact_search` class where you want to apply the same code.

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: why not just trigger the event handler when you want it to happen? `$('#contact_search').keyup()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass value to the function as shown below

```
function ContactSearch(value) {
            var $rows = $('#contact_table tbody tr');
            var val = $.trim(value).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

            $rows.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();
        }
```

and call function as shown below

```
if($("#contact_search").val()) {
    ContactSearch($("#contact_search").val());// pass required value
}
$('#contact_search').keyup(function() {
    ContactSearch($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function ContactSearch() {
        var $rows = $(document).find('#contact_table tbody tr');
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function ContactSearch() {
var th = $("#contact_search");
            var $rows = $('#contact_table tbody tr');
            var val = $.trim($(th).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

            $rows.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(th).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any element so currently `this` is not correct, try to pass the element to the function:

```
function ContactSearch(el) {
            var $rows = $('#contact_table tbody tr');
            var val = $.trim($(el).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

            $rows.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use $(this) inside the function,

refer any var to #content_search

```
   function ContactSearch() {
    var $x = $("#contact_search");
    var $rows = $('#contact_table tbody tr');
    var val = $.trim($x.val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $x.text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is out of context within your function.  You will need to either pass it as a parameter or replace your `$(this)` selectors with `$('#contact_search')`.

Answer (score 0):

Make it as:

```
function ContactSearch($this) {
        var $rows = $('#contact_table tbody tr');
        var val = $.trim($this).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
    }
```

Call it as:

```
 $('#contact_search').keyup(function() {
   ContactSearch($(this).val());
   });
```